# how to change install location of "winget"?

Tags: windows-10, path, winget

I want to change the install path of winget (the package manager for windows) to `D:\Program Files\{insert folder name}`. This is the command I was told to use on the documentation

```
winget install --id {insert program id} --location "D:\Program Files\{insert folder name}"
```

But instead it installs the file in `D:\Program`

So what I understood is it reads the location up to the space and creates the folder until there. To make sure I used a folder name without space and it installed correctly.

I posted this question on *StackOverflow* initially but it got flagged as computer hardware/software and told me to post it here, how does this come under that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This feature is proposed in
[Can the software installation path be set? #489](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/489).

The answer on Jul 11, 2020 was:

> There is already a function in Winget, use `winget install Software.Name --location "C:\Folder\Software.Name"`
>
> **However the support is limited right now**.
>
> BUT, we also just got support for Interactive mode winget install
> Software.Name `-i`, which is a safer option then `--location` right
> now.

The `location` option is new and is likely to have bugs, and it seems
that you have found one.

The best solution is perhaps to wait for this to be fixed, and to add
a bug report to https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues.

If the `-i` solution is not an option, you might as temporary
workaround move manually the contents of the folder on `C` to `D` and
replace the `C` folder by a symbolic link to the `D` folder.

For more information see
[The Complete Guide to Creating Symbolic Links (aka Symlinks) on Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20210227103827/https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).

Comment: It now works as expected.

Comment: [if supported (learn.windows.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/install) (a gotcha for N00bs), suspect some application developers want installation in specific location.

Comment: Does not work for all programs. Some install to c:\program files which is a pain for those of us with small C drives and large external drives, as it's not easy to alias those internal windows install programs.

Comment: how-to-geek link is dead

Comment: @not2qubit: Thank you - the link was replaced from archive.org.

Comment: One of my personal favorite references to links in windows is the [LSE site](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) and tool.

Answer (score 3):

you can use "Progra~1" for "Program Files" and "Progra~2" for "Program Files (x86)". this is an error caused by powershell or cmd syntax, and not because of winget. You need to convert your path to any form without spaces or any special characters, that should be a regular habit, if you don't want to face these kind of issues.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Comment: Using quotes didn't solve my issue and I used "Progra~1" to solve it, and this was the missing answer for this question. I think this is something new, right?

Comment: Well, it is actually winget's fault. WinGet needs to properly quote the install dir argument, which it does for Burn, Msi, Wix and Inno format install packages (and probably some others), but **NOT** for Nullsoft installers. See here: https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/blob/master/src/AppInstallerCommonCore/Manifest/ManifestCommon.cpp#L581
Also, while using 8.3 names can be a quick & dirty workaround, you have to be really cautious with that. 8.3 can be disabled and the numbers aren't stable. (i.e. "Program Files" could be "PROGRA~2" or "PROGRA~4"). Never script winget with 8.3 names!

Comment: This seems like something substantial to add. Up/down votes are supposed to take care of determining whether an answer is helpful. Why discourage potentially helpful input?

Comment: Instead of guessing which name the folder has in 8.3 format, you always can use "dir * /x"
This shows all file and folder names within the current directory in 8.3 format.